# PHP PDO Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined using Q-mark parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**EDIT**: You're not allowed to have the word "question" in the title. Q-mark means "question-mark"

**EDIT 2**: Realized I should remove my personal contact info from the dummy customer record

I'm trying to making some basic functions to reduce maintenance of a recent project. Among these is the following simple function so I can add columns to the database at a later date without needing to change my update queries:

```
function update( $table, $fields ) {
    global $db; // A slightly modified PDO object
    if( count( $fields ) > 0 ) {
        $query = "UPDATE `" . $table . "` SET ";
        foreach( $customer as $key => $value ) {
            $query .= "`" . $key . "` = ?, ";
        }
        $query = substr( $query, 0, -2 );
        $query .= " WHERE `id` = " . $_REQUEST['id'];
        $db->prepare( $query );
        $db->execute( $fields );
    } else { return true; }
}
```

This function was working when I passed one or two fields, but the moment I tried passing more it failed. Here's the query, value of `$fields`, and error I'm receiving:

Query:

```
string 'UPDATE `customers` SET `5v` = ?, `contactaddress` = ?, `contactaddress2` = ?, `contactcity` = ?, `contactemail` = ?, `contactname` = ?, `contactphone` = ?, `contactstate` = ?, `contactzip` = ?, `corrugated` = ?, `name` = ?, `permalok` = ?, `residential` = ?, `secureseam` = ?, `tax` = ? WHERE `id` = 1' (length=301)
```

$fields:

```
array
  '5v' => string '120' (length=3)
  'contactaddress' => string '999 Street Dr' (length=13)
  'contactaddress2' => string 'Apt 2' (length=7)
  'contactcity' => string 'City' (length=9)
  'contactemail' => string 'steven.abarnett@gmail.com' (length=25)
  'contactname' => string 'Steven Barnett' (length=14)
  'contactphone' => string '(555) 555-5555' (length=14)
  'contactstate' => string 'KY' (length=2)
  'contactzip' => string '55555' (length=5)
  'corrugated' => string '90' (length=2)
  'name' => string 'Steven's Metals' (length=15)
  'permalok' => string '130' (length=3)
  'residential' => string '100' (length=3)
  'secureseam' => string '130' (length=3)
  'tax' => string '6' (length=1)
```

Error:

```
string 'Statement execution failed: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' (length=96)
```

Googling this error, it sounds like an issue with *named* parameters, not *question-mark* parameters. Why am I getting this error?

**UPDATE**:

I've been continuing to debug and experiment and tracing the error I found it's not the statement execution that fails, but attempting to fetch the result afterwards.

In my modified PDO object I have the following code within my `execute()` method:

```
    // Load from database
    try {
        $this->stmt->execute( $args );
        $this->lastid = $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        $this->data = $this->stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = 'Statement execution failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
```

Placing `echo` statements between each line in the `try{}` section shows that the first two lines run without a hitch, but the third line is throwing the exception.

Is there are reason my query would fail with a general error when I call `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`?

**FINAL UPDATE:**

As it turns out [PDO and Mysql haven't been playing nicely for 6 years](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35793). The general solution seems to be to unset the PDOStatement object after each call to `PDOStatement::execute()`, however this didn't work for me. The issue stems from the fact that MySQL can only have one cursor open at a time pointing to records in a record set, so another proposed solution is to use `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` instead of `PDOStatement::fetch()` OR to call `PDOStatement::closeCusor()`. Again, this didn't work for me. My issue comes from certain installations of MySQL which will create a cursor during `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries (all of which return no data) which can not be closed since it's pointing to null data.

My solution was to only call `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` when I'm running a query that return data. I have a `queryhash` variable which was used in caching (the big modification I made to the PDO class) which was set to `false` for these three query types (since you need to send the query to the database rather than deferring to cache). I simply modified my `execute()` function to check this variable and only call `fetchAll()` if it was not set to false.

Comment: `id = $_REQUEST['id']` needs to be prepared as well

Comment: @Pills: That didn't help. Still getting the HY000 general error that I got when I changed to numeric keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be using an index array instead of an associative one.

```
array(
    '120',
    '750 Shaker Dr',
    'Apt 505',
    'Lexington', 
    'steven.abarnett@gmail.com', 
    'Steven Barnett', 
    '(859) 402-7760', 
    'KY',
    '40504', 
    '90',
    "Steven's Metals",
    '130',
    '100',
    '130',
    '6'
)
```

Comment: `array_values` will make that very easy

Comment: Getting a new error now. `string 'Statement execution failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' (length=58)`

Comment: Found the new error is slightly more complicated (also fixed it) - although using `array_values` did solve the first error, ergo answer accepted. I'll add a note to the question to describe how I fixed the new error.

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 5.2, the array passed to `execute()` must have identical keys to those in the statement string.  Since you have used `?`, PDO is expecting a numerically indexed array passed to `execute()` not an associative array.  When constructing your `$fields` array, just append each value onto it in the correct order and don't specify a key.   Alternatively, extract them to a numerically-indexed array with `array_values()`:

```
$db->execute(array_values($fields));
```

See the [docs on `PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

> 5.2.0  The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was silently ignored.

Comment: That explains why I never had this issue before. Updated from 5.0.4 this past week. As in my other comment using array_values() gives me a new error: `string 'Statement execution failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' (length=58)`